# Не работает очистка в калькуляторе Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, калькулятор, pydroid

Пишу для себя калькулятор на `Tkinter` в `Pydroid 3`. Но у меня не работает функция `clear()`, которая должна очищать дисплей калькулятора. Если что, переменная `buffer` - это математический пример, записанный списком посимвольно. Потом он преобразуется в строку и решается командой `eval()`. Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы очистка кнопкой <kbd>C</kbd> (функция `clear`) работала? Также, если не сложно, подскажите, как выровнять текст в надписи `disp` так, чтобы он был в правом нижнем углу. Вот код программы:

```py
from tkinter import *


buffer = []


def close():
    try:
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
    except:
        pass


def displaybuffer():
    try:
        disp['text'] = ''.join(buffer)
    except:
        pass


def add1():
    try:
        buffer.append('1')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add2():
    try:
        buffer.append('2')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add3():
    try:
        buffer.append('3')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add4():
    try:
        buffer.append('4')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add5():
    try:
        buffer.append('5')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add6():
    try:
        buffer.append('6')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add7():
    try:
        buffer.append('7')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add8():
    try:
        buffer.append('8')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add9():
    try:
        buffer.append('9')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def add0():
    try:
        buffer.append('0')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def addl():
    try:
        buffer.append('(')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def addr():
    try:
        buffer.append(')')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def addc():
    try:
        buffer.append('.')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def adda():
    try:
        buffer.append('+')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def adds():
    try:
        buffer.append('-')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def addm():
    try:
        buffer.append('*')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def addd():
    try:
        buffer.append('/')
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass


def clear():
    try:
        buffer = []
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass

def bksp():
    try:
        buffer.pop()
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass


def result():
    try:
        res = str(eval(''.join(buffer)))
        if res.endswith('.0'):
            res = str(int(float(res)))
        disp['text'] = res
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        disp['text'] = '!ZER'
    except SyntaxError:
        disp['text'] = '!SYN'
    except:
        disp['text'] = '!ERR'


root = Tk()
root.title('Калькулятор')
root.geometry('690x1320')
root['bg'] = '#555'

disp = Label(root, text=''.join(buffer), bg='#6B6', fg='black', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 17), height=7)
disp.pack(fill=BOTH)

kbd1 = Frame(root, bg='#444')
kbd1.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

kbd2 = Frame(root, bg='#444')
kbd2.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

kbd3 = Frame(root, bg='#444')
kbd3.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

kbd4 = Frame(root, bg='#444')
kbd4.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

kbd5 = Frame(root, bg='#444')
kbd5.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

Button(kbd1, text='C', bg='red', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=clear).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd1, text='(', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=addl).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd1, text=')', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=addr).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd1, text='/', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=addd).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd2, text='7', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add7).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd2, text='8', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add8).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd2, text='9', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add9).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd2, text='*', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=addm).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd3, text='4', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add4).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd3, text='5', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add5).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd3, text='6', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add6).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd3, text='-', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=adds).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd4, text='1', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add1).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd4, text='2', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add2).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd4, text='3', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add3).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd4, text='+', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=adda).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd5, text='<', bg='purple', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=bksp).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd5, text='0', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=add0).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd5, text='.', bg='gray', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=addc).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

Button(kbd5, text='=', bg='green', fg='white', activebackground='#555', activeforeground='white', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 22), command=result).pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', close)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас внутри функции `clear` `buffer` - это локальная переменная. Поэтому после того как вы ее переопределяете внутри функции, вне функции она не изменяется. Как вариант, вы можете внутри функции `clear` дописать `global buffer`, тогда будет изменяться глобальная переменная, и поле будет очищаться:

```
def clear():
    global buffer
    try:
        buffer = []
        displaybuffer()
    except:
        pass
```

По поводу текста внутри лейбла - используйте якорь `anchor`, чтобы привязывать текст к определенной стороне виджета. Он может принимать значения: `n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, center`. `n` - nord - Север, т.е. верх виджета, `ne` - northeast - Северо-Восток, т.е. верхний правый угол. Вам нужен правый нижний - это Юго-Восток - `se`

```
disp = Label(root, text=''.join(buffer), bg='#6B6', fg='black', font=('Droid Sans Mono', 17), height=7, anchor='se')
disp.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clear():
    try:
        displaybuffer([])
    except:
        pass
```